# How to remove the field 'prevPwd' from the formbuilder in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here's the code:

***TS***

```
user = true;

this.fb.group({
      password: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        this.passwordValidator
      ]],
      newPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
      prevPwd: ['',
        Validators.required
      ]
    });
```

What I'm trying to do here is to remove the `prevPwd` or previous password field, when the user is true, but when user is false it should be required the field `prevPwd`.

I already tried.

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
          password: ['', [
            Validators.required,
            this.passwordValidator
          ]],
          newPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
          prevPwd: ['',
            Validators.required
          ]
        });
if (user) {
 this.formGroup.removeControl('prevPwd');
}

return this.formGroup
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not `removeControls` function, its `removeControl` function.

```
 this.formGroup.removeControl("prevPwd");
```

This will work.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-function-in-child-h14vy?file=/src/app/action.component.ts)

Comment: when I try to console the formGroup, the old field still on the controls.

Comment: Updated the answer. Working sample I have added, check the link.

Comment: on my side, when I try to open the drawer it doesn't change/remove the control ```prevPwd```.
I added a code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-function-in-child-forked-puzz4?file=/src/app/action.component.ts

Comment: How I gonna set the ```prevPwd``` to be not required when the user is ```true```?

Comment: so you want to keep the field but dynamically add the validation?